# Using multiple ternaries in ng-style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ternary-operator

I am wondering how you could have/ if you should have multiple ternaries within the html

I am trying to change font size if a property exists to true.  In this case the condition  **isJP** works just fine.

```
ng-style="isJP() ? {'font-size':'8125em'} : {'font-size':'16px'}">
```

If I want to also consider languagePath === 'en' I am not so fortunate on this.

```
isJP() ? languagePath ==='en'? {'font-size':'.8125em'} : {'font-size':'16px'}
```

This last effort made no sense to create 2 next to each other, but I tried to see what would happen.

```
isJP() ? {'font-size':'.8125em'} : {'font-size':'16px'}, languagePath === 'eng'? {'font-size':'.8125em'} : {'font-size':'16px'}">
```

Wondering what is the best approach in this matter.  I definitely want to add change the font size on both  **isJP()**  and **languagePath ==='en'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

`"(isJP() || languagePath === 'en') ? {'font-size': '8.125em'} : {'font-size': '16px'}"`

---

Another option would be to define a function in your angular code that checks both conditions, like

`useRelativeFont = function () { return (isJP() || languagePath === 'en') }`

...and then use `useRelativeFont()` in your ng-style ternary.